# Showing Splash screen spinner in ionic

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I want to show spinner on splash screen using ionic framework in android.Here is my config file:

```
<content src="index.html"/>
  <access origin="*"/>
  <preference name="splashScreen" value="screen"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000"/>
  <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false"/>
  <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
  <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>

   <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="true"/>
  <feature name="StatusBar">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVStatusBar" onload="true"/>
  </feature>
```

Answer (score 3):

use

```
<preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="true" />
```

in your config.xml

Comment: I see that in the config source with the question.

Answer (score 1):

1. Install splash screen plugin

> $ ionic plugin add org.apache.cordova.splashscreen

2. Change the defaults.xml in myapp/platforms/ios/cordova/ and config.xml

> ```
> <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
> <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />
> ```

3. Add in your controllers.js on top

> angular.module('starter.controllers', [])
>
> .run(function($ionicPlatform) {
>    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
>      setTimeout(function() {
>          navigator.splashscreen.hide();
>      }, 300);
>   });
>   })

4. Rebuild and run the app:

> ios
>
> $ `ionic cordova build ios` Or
>   $ `ionic cordova run ios`
>
> Android
>
> $ `ionic cordova build android` Or
>   $ `ionic cordova run android`

[For Details](https://medium.com/ionic-tnt/ionic-hide-splash-screen-when-app-is-ready-aba5184684e2#.el71h72b4)

Answer (score -2):

As far as i understand the [documentation](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen), there is no option for displaying the spinner under android.